# Mayavi crashes with "Illegal hardware instruction" on MacOS 10.12

Tags: python, macos, mayavi

Mayavi crashes on my MacOS 10.12. Is there any suggestion?

I installed mayavi and vtk with

```
$ brew install vtk
$ pip install --user mayavi
```

and when I run mayavi2 or import mayavi.lab in python2.7, it crashes

```
$ mayavi2
[1]    93511 illegal hardware instruction  mayavi2

$ python2 -c "import mayavi.mlab"
[1]    93920 illegal hardware instruction  python2 -c "import mayavi.mlab"
```

---

Update

I find the problem may be in `traitsui.api` imported in `mayavi.preferences.preference_manager` .

```
$ python2 -c "import traitsui.api"
[1]    2421 illegal hardware instruction  python2 -c "import traitsui.api"
```

---

Update2

Going deeper, I find it's about "traits.api.Color"... used in traitsui.editors.code_editor

```
$ python -c "from traits.api.Color; print 'hi'; Color( 0xECE9D8 )"
hi
[1]    6414 illegal hardware instruction  python2 -c "from traits.api import Color; print 'hi'; Color(0xECE9D8)"
```

Comment: Hi, you can indeed dig deeper but ultimately the problem is related to loading either traits, vtk or the gui toolbox (qt or wx). Is there not mayavi in brew? Else, you can try to update wxpython or pyqt to see if it helps. Sorry for the lack of precision though, this is hard to debug from a distance.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl THANK YOU VERY MUCH! I tried to re-install pyqt and it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to the suggestion from @PierredeBuyl.

I tried to reinstall pyqt and it works now!

The steps are:

```
$ brew install pyqt
Error: pyqt-4.11.3 already installed
To install this version, first `brew unlink pyqt`

$ brew unlink pyqt
Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/pyqt/4.11.3... 78 symlinks removed

$ brew install pyqt
...

$ mayavi2    # now it works
```